# Is there a way to restore sql server to default settings?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Basically i want all constraints, rules, keys , databases everything removed i want it as it was on the day i installed it . I do not want to re install it. Simply deleting database might not fix the problem i have

Comment: in that case just create a new database and delete the old one

Comment: possibly related, they're talking about express, but I'm sure if non-express had something, they'd mention it: http://serverfault.com/questions/11756/is-there-a-way-to-reset-sql-server-2008-express-to-default-configuration-and-dat

Comment: You say deleting databases might not fix the problem you have.  What exactly is the problem you have?

Comment: The database is adding time 12:00:00 to the dates which are imported .I am importing excel sheet into database 
 DataTable dt7 = new DataTable();
                dt7.Load(dr);
                DataRow[] ExcelRows = new DataRow[dt7.Rows.Count];
                // Bulk Copy to SQL Server
                using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(sqlConnectionString))
                {
                    bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "ExcelTable";

                    dt7.Rows.CopyTo(ExcelRows, 0);

                    for (int i = 0; i < ExcelRows.Length; i++)//i represents the row

Comment: {
                        var oldDate = ExcelRows[i]["data"].ToString();
                        var newDate = Convert.ToDateTime(oldDate);

                        ExcelRows[i]["data"] = newDate.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
                    }

                    bulkCopy.WriteToServer(ExcelRows);